# The website encountered an error while retrieving http://www.mysite.com/dashboard/add-item.xhtml

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces, custom-error-pages, apache-tomee

One user of the app I currently work got the following response in his browser:

> The website encountered an error while retrieving http://www.mysite.com/dashboard/add-item.xhtml. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

`/dashboard/add-item.xhtml` is a JSF page that works without problems most of the time.
Why did TomEE show this page? I have set a special error page in `web.xml`, so this shouldn't have been shown. Application stage is Production as well.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/errors/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <location>/errors/general.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

For all other errors, `/errors/general.xhtml` is rendered as a response, but not in the case I mentioned. I don't have enough information to reproduce the error, but I'm surprised by the result.

Any ideas for fixing/preventing this?

I am using Apache TomEE 1.6.0-2013.09.20 dev + MyFaces that comes with it (2.1.12).

Comment: Is the webapp proxied by another server, e.g. Apache HTTPD?

Comment: No. Just Tomee on port 80. BTW, thanks for editing.

Comment: @BalusC: Do you have any idea for the following bug, please? I'm really really in a big trouble because of it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992241/random-jsf-error-no-saved-view-state-could-be-found/18999855 There is a very long discussion happening there, but without results :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but because this error happened just once, and because DigitalOcean was doing maintenance in their datacenter in that day, I assume it was not something related to my application nor to Tomee, but just because of the VPS provider, DigitalOcean in this case.